# Xamarin Dependency Services does not work with higher Android version

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have programmed a Xamarin app that uses a native Android function through Dependency Service. Specifically it is about WifiManager and the method SetWifiEnabled() which is for turning off Wifi. Using Android 7.1 emulator with API 25 everything works and I can turn off the wifi. With emulator with Android version 11 and API 30 the wifi is not turned off which I assume that the method SetWifiEnabled() does not work. The wifi is not turned off. Does anyone know the reason for this ?
Thanks a lot

Here is the Code from Dependency Service:

```
[assembly: Dependency(typeof(GetWifimanager))]
namespace WifiSwitch.Droid
{
    public class GetWifimanager : IWifiManager
    {
        [Obsolete]
        public bool CheckWifi()
        {
            var wifiManager = (WifiManager)Android.App.Application.Context.GetSystemService(Context.WifiService);

            return wifiManager != null && wifiManager.SetWifiEnabled(false);
            
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

according to the [docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiManager#setWifiEnabled(boolean))

> This method was deprecated in API level 29. Starting with
> Build.VERSION_CODES#Q, applications are not allowed to enable/disable
> Wi-Fi. Compatibility Note: For applications targeting
> Build.VERSION_CODES.Q or above, this API will always fail and return
> false. If apps are targeting an older SDK (Build.VERSION_CODES.P or
> below), they can continue to use this API.